# Xlwings - unable to insert values for a range of rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I am trying to insert a value `n` into a specific `H` column from position H10:H20

So, I tried the below

```
start_index = int(10)
for n in range(20):
    print(type(n))  # this returns int
    range('H' + str(start_index)).value = n
    start_index = start_index + 1
```

However, the above code results in the below error

```
      2 for n in range(20):
      3     print(type(n))
----> 4     range('H' + str(start_index)).value = n
      5     start_index = start_index + 1

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

But my `n` is an integer.

Comment: The built-in range function (that you are calling at line number 4) takes integer as input.

Comment: but that's excel range

Comment: But the script doesn't know that. It is treating the range as a built-in function

Comment: okay, so what can be done? Do you xlwings?

Comment: Try `from xlwings import range as xlrange`. and rename the code at line 4 as `xlrange`. Or use `import xlwings` and at line 4 say `xlwings.range`. Try to avoid asterisk in your import statements in order to avoid polluting the namespace

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help. I just realised that if I prefix sheet.range, the error went away

Comment: Sure me or someone else will help but please do post reproducible code along with import statements in order to avoid mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following
`from xlwings import range as xlrange` and rename the code at line 4 as `xlrange`.

Or use `import xlwings` and at line 4 use `xlwings.range`.

Try to avoid asterisk in your import statements in order to avoid polluting the namespace. For more info check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)